# error in importing kivy module. "ModuleNotFoundError". import error

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, kivy, conda

I installed kivy using

```
conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

and now when I am trying to import kivy it shows me this error

```
PS C:\Users\HP\programming> & C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
c:/Users/HP/programming/kivy_apps/first-app/app1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\HP\programming\kivy_apps\first-app\app1.py", line 15, in <module>
import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

and my code was just

```
import kivy
```

what should I do know?

for those who want additional information i tried to reinstall kivy using pip and the same conda command and it shows all requirements satisfied

[image]

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
```

is a python installation that does not come from your anaconda. You have installed `kivy` for your anaconda installed interpreter, you will need to call your python script with that interpreter.

I would also recommend to uninstall all other python installations, as seperating them from the anaconda installation is not that trivial if you are a beginner. Instead, just create a virtual conda env when you want to use different python versions

Comment: Can I know upto which versions of python kivy is supported.